# Domain Model id with equality and SqlAlchemy autoincrement?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, domain-driven-design

Say I have a domain model with an id field plus **eq** and **hash**. Then there is a simple SqlAlchemy ORM mapping.

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
  _id: int
  value: 50

def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Foo):
        return False
    return other._id == self._id

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self._id)

foo = Table(
    "foo",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("_id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("value", Float, nullable=False)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Foo, foo)
```

This seems simple enough and follows the documentation for SqlAlchemy. My problem is the _id column/property. If I create a test to load Foo from the database:

```
def test_foo_mapper_can_load_foos(session):
    with session:
        session.execute(
            'INSERT INTO foo (value)'
            'VALUES (50)'
        )
        session.commit()
    
    expected = [ 
        Foo(_id=1, value=50),
        ]

    assert session.query(Foo).all() == expected
```

this works, fine. The model is initialised with ids from the database.

But, what about initialising a model to commit *to the database*. If the client creates a new foo to try to write to the database, how should I approach the id for the model, before gets committed?

```
def test_foo_mapper_can_save_foos(session):
    #option1 - manually set it (collides with auto_increment)
    new_foo = Foo(_id=1, value: 50)
    #option2  - set to None (collides with __eq__/hashing)
    new foo = Foo(_id=None, value: 50)
    #option3 - get rid of id from domain model and only have it in db
    new_foo = Foo(value: 50)
    
session.add(new_foo)
        session.commit()
        rows = list(session.execute('SELECT * FROM "foo"'))
        assert rows == [(1, 50)]
```

Each of the test options can work, but none of the implementations seem like good code.

In option 1, when the client creates a new foo an id must be set, the dataclass requires it in the constructor... but it seems to not really be in line with the auto_increment primary key idea on the table - the client can pass any id, whether it is the next in sequence or not and the mapper will try to use it. I feel the database should be responsible for setting primary key.

So, on to option 2. Set the id to None, and the database will take care of it on commit. However, the **eq** and **hash** functions rely on id for equality and the object becomes unhashable. This could also be done by setting _id: int = None as a default value on the domain model itself. But again, seems like a bad solution.

Finally option 3... remove the _id field from the domain model... which has popped up in a couple of articles, but also seem less than ideal as Foo now has no unique id for use in select statements, and use in other business logic etc...

I'm sure I'm thinking about this all wrong, I just can't figure out where.